# getElementsAnnotatedWith method returns empty list while annotation processing

Tags: java, code-generation, annotation-processing, annotation-processor

My goal is code generation via annotation processor. I want to generate new class on the top of the existent base class by excluding some fields according to annotations and adding some constarint validators etc. I have 3 modules. First one is base module which contains Car class and annotations BaseClass, A and B. Second module is annotation processor module. It contains CustomCodeGenerator annotaion and its processor. And third module is the module which I want to generate NewCar class onto it and use that NewCar class in it.

Car.Class

```
@BaseClass
public class Car {

    @A
    private int seatCount;

    @B
    private String name;

    private String dummy;

    public Car(int seatCount, String name) {
        this.seatCount = seatCount;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getSeatCount() {

        return seatCount;
    }

    public void setSeatCount(int seatCount) {

        this.seatCount = seatCount;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
   }

    public String getDummy() {
    return dummy;
    }

    public void setDummy(String dummy) {
        this.dummy = dummy;
    }
}
```

CustomCodeGenerator.class

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface CustomCodeGenerator {
}
```

CustomCodeGeneratorProcessor.class

```
import com.squareup.javapoet.*;

import javax.annotation.processing.*;
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.element.AnnotationMirror;
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import javax.lang.model.element.Modifier;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;
import javax.lang.model.util.Elements;
import javax.lang.model.util.Types;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@SupportedAnnotationTypes("*")
public class CustomCodeGeneratorProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    private Filer filer;
    private Messager messager;
    private Elements elementUtils;
    private Types typeUtils;

    @Override
    public synchronized void init(ProcessingEnvironment processingEnvironment) {
        super.init(processingEnvironment);
        filer = processingEnvironment.getFiler();
        messager = processingEnvironment.getMessager();
        elementUtils = processingEnvironment.getElementUtils();
        typeUtils = processingEnvironment.getTypeUtils();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        if (!roundEnv.processingOver()) {
            try {
                Set<? extends Element> elementsAnnotatedWith = roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(BaseClass.class);
                for (Element element : elementsAnnotatedWith) {
                    TypeElement element1 = (TypeElement) element;
                    List<? extends Element> enclosedElements = element1.getEnclosedElements();

                    MethodSpec main = MethodSpec.constructorBuilder()
                            .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC)
                            .addParameter(Integer.class, "seatCount")
                            .addStatement("this.$N = $N", "seatCount", "seatCount")
                            .build();

                    TypeSpec.Builder builder = TypeSpec.classBuilder("NewCar")
                            .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC)
                            .addAnnotation(AnnotationSpec.builder(ClassName.get("", "ValidPassengerCount")).build())
                            .addMethod(main);
                    outer:
                    for (Element enclosedElement : enclosedElements) {
                        if (enclosedElement.getKind().isField()) {
                            List<? extends AnnotationMirror> annotationMirrors = enclosedElement.getAnnotationMirrors();
                            for (AnnotationMirror declaredAnnotation : annotationMirrors) {
                                if (!typeUtils.isSameType(elementUtils.getTypeElement("A").asType(), declaredAnnotation.getAnnotationType())) {
                                    continue outer;
                                }
                            }
                            builder.addField(TypeName.get(enclosedElement.asType()), enclosedElement.getSimpleName().toString(), Modifier.PUBLIC);

                        }
                    }

                    JavaFile javaFile = JavaFile.builder("", builder.build())
                            .build();

                    javaFile.writeTo(filer);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public SourceVersion getSupportedSourceVersion() {
        return SourceVersion.latestSupported();
    }
}
```

The third module is like below as well.

Main.class

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory;
import java.util.Set;

@CustomCodeGenerator
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {



        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

        NewCar car = new NewCar(-1);

        Set<ConstraintViolation<NewCar>> violationSet = validator.validate(car);
        System.out.println(violationSet.iterator().next().getMessage());

    }
}
```

ValidPassengerCount.class

```
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@Target({TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {ValidPassengerCountValidator.class})
public @interface ValidPassengerCount {

    String message() default "invalid passenger count!";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

ValidPassengerCountValidator.class

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class ValidPassengerCountValidator
        implements ConstraintValidator<ValidPassengerCount, NewCar> {

    public void initialize(ValidPassengerCount constraintAnnotation) {
    }

    public boolean isValid(NewCar car, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (car == null) {
            return true;
        }

        return 0 <= car.seatCount;
    }
}
```

The problem is roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(BaseClass.class) in CustomCodeGeneratorProcessor.class returns empty list. If I move Car into the 3rd module it works. However my goal is generating new code from the base class which comes from dependent module which is module 1 for this example. Is there any way to reach annotated elements of dependent module?

Comment: Methods of RoundEnvironment, such as `getElementsAnnotatedWith` and `getRootElements` don't consider already compiled classes — only ones, that are currently being compiled. If your target class is placed in another "module", it is likely to be already be built by the time your processor gets to run, so you won't be able to look it up by annotation.